# Angular update view after AJAX call

Tags: ajax, angularjs, passport.js

I'm having issues waiting for a callback from authService.login().  My view is being updated before the user is done being logged in.  I'll walk us through the code.

Setting up Angular app:

```
var htsApp = angular.module('htsApp', []);
```

Below I am configuring Angular to make XHR requests:

```
htsApp.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

loginPassport() is triggered when the user submits the login form.  This calls my authService.login() from my Angular factory but the code to update the view is not waiting for callback before executing. help?

```
function loginController($scope, $sce, authService){

    $scope.loginPassport = function() {  //gets called when user clicks login button

        var email = $scope.email;
        var password = $scope.password;

        authService.login(email, password, function(res) {

            //This code is being run before callback is received!!!
            //Update my view in Angular

            $scope.loginMenuContainer = $sce.trustAsHtml(authService.getLoginModuleHtml());
        });


    };
};
```

authService.login() logs in user asynchronously

```
htsApp.factory('authService', function($http, Session){
    return {
        login: function(email, password, callback){
            $http.post("/login", {"email":email, "password":password})
                .success(callback, function(passportRes) {

                    if(passportRes.success){ //We are logged in!!

                        Session.create(passportRes.user.email, passportRes.user.id);

                    } else { //There was an error logging the user in

                    }

                //Passport JS Middleware Error
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

                });
        },
        isLoggedIn: function(){ //Check if user is logged in

            return !!Session.email;

        },
        getLoginModuleHtml: function(){ //Get correct HTML if user is logged in or not

            var html = '';

            if(this.isLoggedIn()){
                html = '<div>html if user is logged in</div>';
            } else {
                html ='<div>html is user is logged out!</div>';
            }

            return html;
        }
    }
});
```

This service is used to store user information in a session

```
htsApp.service('Session', function () {
    this.create = function (email, id) {
        this.email = email;
        this.id = id;
    };
    this.destroy = function () {
        this.email = null;
        this.id = null;
    };
    return this;
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promise and $a to sort this out more here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

**authService:**

```
htsApp.factory('authService', function ($http, $q, Session)
{
    return {

        login: function (email, password)
        {
            var deffered = $q.defer();

            $http.post("/login", { "email": email, "password": password })

                //sucess
                .then(function (passportRes)
                {

                    if (passportRes.success) { //We are logged in!!

                        Session.create(passportRes.user.email, passportRes.user.id);
                        deffered.resolve();

                    } else { //There was an error logging the user in

                    }


                },
                //error
                function (data, status, headers, config)
                {
                    deffered.reject();

                });

            return deffered.promise;

        },
        isLoggedIn: function ()
        { //Check if user is logged in

            return !!Session.email;

        },
        getLoginModuleHtml: function ()
        { //Get correct HTML if user is logged in or not

            var html = '';

            if (this.isLoggedIn()) {
                html = '<div>html if user is logged in</div>';
            } else {
                html = '<div>html is user is logged out!</div>';
            }

            return html;
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller**

```
function loginController($scope, $sce, authService)
{

    $scope.loginPassport = function ()
    {  //gets called when user clicks login button

        var email = $scope.email;
        var password = $scope.password;

        authService.login(email, password).then(function ()
        {
            $scope.loginMenuContainer = $sce.trustAsHtml(authService.getLoginModuleHtml());
        }, function ()
        {
            alert("login error");
        });
    };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into promises. You need to set up a promise for the app to be able to wait for the login to succeed.

You have to do that because AngularJS is async by nature and setting up a promise will make the part wait for the promise to be returned and then execute whatever part of the app needs to wait for that information to arrive.

Check out this blog post about promises. I think it explains it quite well.

http://andyshora.com/promises-angularjs-explained-as-cartoon.html